# Is there an existing workflow for Javascript module code isolation?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, iife, umd, rollup-plugin-babel

When making an app to run on a web page with ES6 code, multiple instances of the app have conflicts when using static variables or singletons.

Iframes are commonly used and provide code isolation between the instances. For example, an ad on a website can be embedded without conflicting with another ad.

One method I've seen suggested and works ok is to publish the application as an IIFE/UMD using Babel and then wrap this inside a function where the function runs the IIFE, creating a new instance of the entire app, including dependencies and returns the exports as an API. This isolates statics and singletons.

```
export wrappedModule = function() {
    var module = {IIFE bundle, which exposes exports};
    return exposedExports;
}
```

This works but I'm trying to figure out how best to automate the wrapping. So far, I setup a module and used a copy/replace process to embed the entire UMD/IIFE output from Babel inside the wrapped function.

Everything works but it feels like a method that shouldn't be relied on for production builds because the final output is being patched together manually.

I looked into making a custom Babel plugin to transform the code based on the Babel UMD plugin by modifying the buildWrapper. This is quite complex to setup but I will try to get this working if there isn't a simpler way:

https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-plugin-transform-modules-umd/src/index.ts

Is there an existing production workflow (bundlers, plugins etc) for isolating entire Javascript module code in a wrapper function? I read some mentions of embedded Javascript widgets like the following that reference Google Analytics widgets:

https://blog.jenyay.com/building-javascript-widget/

These are usually quite simple apps without dependencies that only need a single instance of the widget so they can just build as a UMD/IIFE without wrapping. For multiple instances of the same widget, there needs to be another layer of isolation.

---

**Added code example.** With embedWrapped, I can create new versions of an entire module with independent statics and singletons unlike with direct imports of embed.js. Even if I added a separate import like import { Embedded as e2 } from "./embed.js";  in page.js, this refers to the same value as the first import.

```
// embed-wrapped.js
export const embedWrapped = function () {
    const isolated = (function () {
        class Embedded { }
        Embedded.value = Math.random();
        window.exported = { Embedded };
    })();
    return window.exported;
}
```

```
// embed.js
export class Embedded { }

Embedded.value = Math.random();
```

```
//page.js
import { Embedded } from "./embed.js";
import { embedWrapped } from "./embed-wrapped.js";

console.log(Embedded.value);

const embed1 = embedWrapped();
console.log(embed1.Embedded.value);

const embed2 = embedWrapped();
console.log(embed2.Embedded.value);
```

Comment: Bundlers generally do this automatically, because modules have their own private scope that is separate from the global scope. That means that as long as your code doesn't depend on being loaded directly into the global scope, you can just bundle it and load it and assume things don't conflict if you load multiple instances.

Comment: With ES6 modules, instances get shared and affects static variables and exported instances.

If module A exports a class with a static variable, when it's imported, the static variable is the same. This is expected.

However, I need a way to have two separate copies of the module on demand so that the static variable is different in each.

Comment: I added a code example, running page.js will show the difference between the wrapped module and directly imported. The wrapped one has the behavior I want but I'm looking for the best way to build that wrapper function.

Comment: "With ES6 modules, instances get shared and affects static variables and exported instances" this isn't exclusive to ES6 modules in any way. Global variables (and their OO counterpart, Singleton instances) are what they are. Just don't use them. It isn't clear what your actual question is here or why you have such a focus on ES modules?

Comment: @adevart Do you need it to be a single thread? Do you need shared variables/objects? Do you need to run unsafe code? 1) use `new Worker('./foo.js')` from `node:worker_threads` 2) 3) use something from `node:vm` 3) use `isolated-vm`

Comment: "Global variables (and their OO counterpart, Singleton instances) are what they are. Just don't use them."

Some of these are inside library dependencies. I need to isolate my code and dependencies (it's a large app like 200k lines of code).

"It isn't clear what your actual question is here or why you have such a focus on ES modules?"

This also applies to Javascript in general. If you do a web search for "embeddable Javascript widgets", this is close to what I need but in an npm module. Consider a web app and then running two instances of it on the same page and they don't conflict.

Comment: @Dimava It doesn't need to share variables/objects between isolated instances or run unsafe code but it does need access to the DOM and window, not sure if workers would be suitable. The isolation I need is in the published npm module, not the browser. In the example code in the original post, I want to wrap my published npm module in a way that when it's used, it's isolated from another instance. Imagine that my npm module is an advertisement that is used on a webpage and I want two copies of it. If I import it into a script and run its bootstrap, the instances conflict with each other.

Comment: In the original post, there's an example that works for me, which is wrapping a UMD export of an npm module inside a function wrapper and instancing the module when the function is called. The function returns an API to create an instance. This isolates everything. I'd like to have a reliable way to publish this kind of setup. I managed to do it via rollup by copying code around but it would be nice to have a Babel transform plugin to do it properly. I can make one but if one exists already or there's a similar workflow available, I would rather use it.

Comment: @adevart It sounds that you need a complete JavaScript sandbox. Even with your wrapped funtion, the global variables can't be isolated in different instances. In browser environment, microfrontends can achive this purpose, like https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa and https://github.com/umijs/qiankun.

Comment: Sharing global variables is ok for my use case but complete isolation is better. Microfrontends look like they are trying to solve this problem. It would be good if Javascript had this built-in.

There seems to be a few different options: single-spa, module federation, open components. There are 11 options listed here: 

https://itnext.io/11-micro-frontends-frameworks-you-should-know-b66913b9cd20

Not sure which is best to use to publish an npm module that provides an isolated component to a consuming Typescript app with an API.

Comment: In fact, I think you should just design your npm module as proper as possible. For example, move each field from static to class member, unless it is shared between different instances.